# Stop Safari from loading webpages as Preview images

Tags: macos, safari, snow-leopard, graphics

Everyday, the first time I start Safari, if I go to the history or bookmarks tab, I get the following message:

[image: safari]

How can I stop Safari from prompting this message and completely disable the webpages Preview?

I already set the update policy to 2 with this:

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari DebugSnapshotsUpdatePolicy -int 2
```

Answer (score 4):

Try running this command in the terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari DidPromptToFetchRecentHistoryPreviews -bool YES
```

Comment: This only works for the current session.